# If im using nouveau there is no way to use vdpau with it?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau, vdpau

Im using ubuntu 12.10 and im using the opensource driver which came reloaded with the distro tried to install the proper driver but I failed, so now im using the opensource driver and its okay, but the only problem is I want to use vdpau coz it accelerate the videos on youtube and smplayer and play it with less cpu usage.

my question is: is there a way to enable vdpau with the opensource driver or do I have to use the proper driver from nvidia ?

Answer (score 1):

Related bug

> Bug #1002224 “Please include gallium vdpau and xvmc driver suppo...” : Bugs : “mesa” package : Ubuntu
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1002224

As far as I can see we'll have to wait for Debian to fix it.

And there's an unofficial PPA software source you can check out

> Updated and Optimized Open Graphics Drivers : Oibaf
>   https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

See http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/VideoAcceleration/. Depending on your graphics card, it may or may not be supported.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this might answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I mamanged to get vdpau working on my Linux Mint 19.3 (Ubuntu 18.04 based) by installing `mesa-vdpau-drivers`:

```
vdpauinfo 
display: :0   screen: 0
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nouveau.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error creating VDPAU device: 1


apt-file search libvdpau_nouveau.so
mesa-vdpau-drivers: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nouveau.so
mesa-vdpau-drivers: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nouveau.so.1
mesa-vdpau-drivers: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nouveau.so.1.0
mesa-vdpau-drivers: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nouveau.so.1.0.0


sudo apt install mesa-vdpau-drivers


vdpauinfo 
display: :0   screen: 0
API version: 1
Information string: G3DVL VDPAU Driver Shared Library version 1.0

Video surface:

name   width height types
-------------------------------------------
420    16384 16384  NV12 YV12 
422    16384 16384  UYVY YUYV 
444    16384 16384  Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 

Decoder capabilities:

name                        level macbs width height
----------------------------------------------------
MPEG1                           0 16384  2048  2048
MPEG2_SIMPLE                    3 16384  2048  2048
MPEG2_MAIN                      3 16384  2048  2048
H264_BASELINE                  41 16384  2048  2048
H264_MAIN                      41 16384  2048  2048
H264_HIGH                      41 16384  2048  2048
VC1_SIMPLE                      1 16384  2048  2048
VC1_MAIN                        2 16384  2048  2048
VC1_ADVANCED                    4 16384  2048  2048
MPEG4_PART2_SP                  3 16384  2048  2048
MPEG4_PART2_ASP                 5 16384  2048  2048
...
```